# How to use AFHTTPSessionManager for a GET request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

So I want to use AFNetworking V2.0 for a GET request with NSURLSession (iOS7's new API)

So far I have got this - but is this the correct way to do it?

```
NSString *tempURL =[NSString stringWithString:url];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    [manager GET:tempURL parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
     {
         //Working

     }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
     {
         //Failed!!

     }];
```

Would this be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Did you run the code, and did it work?

Comment: Yes. But the success block / failure blocks are not called. I think I am missing something?

Comment: I haven't used AFNetworking but do you need to perform some sort of resume before the tasks actually start ?

Comment: No resume needed, for now.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are missing is an `alloc-init` for the `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

Something like this should work (untested):

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api"];
NSString *path = @"resource/1";

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

[manager GET:path parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
 {
     // Success
     NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
 }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
 {
     // Failure
     NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
 }];
```

This would send a GET request to `http://example.com/api/resource/1`.