# AFHTTPSessionManager or AFHTTPOperationManager been skipped, not even executing

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm new to IOS development and was doing something related to dynamic data request through a 3rd party api using `AFNetworing`, I assume this is the good way to do networking in IOS?

One issue I have so far is I have two `AFHTTPSessionManager` in two different class implementation files. When I ran the application, the first one executes successfully. but the second one is not working and the problem is in `debug mode`, I can see that the

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:PLACE_DETAIL_URL
  parameters:@{ @"key": APPLICATION_KEY,
                @"placeid": placeid,
                @"extensions": @"review_summary"
                }
     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
         placeDetail = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary *) [responseObject objectForKey:@"result"]];
     } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Places"
                                                             message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alertView show];
     }];
```

is not even executing. It's been skipped for some reason. Is this a bug or I can only have on `AFHTTPSessionManager` or `AFHTTPOperationManager` at a time?

P.S.
debug gif posted here for clear idea.
[image: debug]

thanks for all your help.

Comment: What part isn't executing?

Comment: I edited the code, looks better. the entire `[manager GET]` part. no failure, neither success.

Comment: Did you check if adding a base URL helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561865/how-to-use-afhttpsessionmanager-for-a-get-request

Comment: That didn't work. the problem is, I had first one working using the same code but in a different class file. `success` and `failure` block weren't executing....

Comment: and you are sure that this piece of code actually gets executed. Did you set a breakpoint in that method?

Comment: yes, I set break point inside the `success` and `failure`, it's weird.

Comment: I added the gif of debugging, sorry about the frames..too fast I guess. The `manager` was returned. but the instance method was never executed.

Comment: seems like you can only have one `AFHTTPSessionManager` running at a time. but when I use `session invalidateCancelTask:` to cancel the session, the second one won't work.